# Composition of binary relations properties

Tags: abstract-algebra, logic, relations, function-and-relation-composition

I'm studying for my exams and I'm stuck at Abstract Algebra. We have $R = ( A , B , G ) , S = ( B , C , H ) , R ′ = ( A , B , G ′ )$ as binary relations: $\operatorname{codom} ( R ) = \operatorname{codom} ( R ′ ) = \operatorname{dom} ( S ) $.

And now we have these properties :

$$S \cdot (R \cap R' ) \subseteq (S \cdot R) \cap (S \cdot R' )$$

$$S \cdot (R \cup R' ) = (S \cdot R) \cup (S \cdot R' )$$

I don't understand why the first one is an inclusion and the second one is an equality.

$$S \cdot (R \cap R') = ( A , C , H \cdot (G \cap G') )$$

$$(S \cdot R) \cap (S \cdot R') = ( A , C , H \cdot G \cap H \cdot G' )$$

$$H \cdot G = \{(a, c) \in A \times C \mid (\exists)b \in B : (a, b) \in G \land (b, c) \in H\}$$

$$H · G' = \{(a, c) \in A \times C \mid (\exists)b \in B : (a, b) \in G' \land (b, c) \in H\}$$

$$H \cdot (G \cap G') = \{(a, c) \in A \times C \mid (\exists)b \in B : (a, b) \in G \land (a, b) \in G' \land (b, c) \in H\}$$

$$H \cdot G \cap H \cdot G' = \{(a, c) \in A \times C \mid (\exists)b \in B : (a, b) \in G \land (b, c) \in H\} \cap \{(a, c) \in A \times C \mid (\exists)b \in B : (a, b) \in G' \land (b, c) \in H\}$$

This is same as :

$$H \cdot G \cap H \cdot G' = \{(a, c) \in A \times C \mid (\exists)b \in B : (a, b) \in G \land (b, c) \in H \land (a, b) \in G' \land (b, c) \in H\}$$

And then since $\land$ is commutative and $(b, c) \in H \land (b, c) \in H = (b, c) \in H $:

$$H \cdot G \cap H \cdot G' = \{(a, c) \in A \times C \mid (\exists)b \in B : (a, b) \in G \land (a, b) \in G' \land (b, c) \in H\}$$

$$H \cdot G \cap H \cdot G' = H \cdot (G \cap G')$$

Same goes for "$\cup$" , just change "$\land$" with "$\lor$" .

What am I missing

PS : If you are downvoting this question ,atleast tell me why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a counterexample to equality in the first case; you'll see by inspecting it where the problem lies in your argument -- in short " you can't pick the same $b$. "

$$
A:=\{0\}; B:=\{1,1'\}; C:=\{2\}\\
G=\{(0,1)\}; G':=\{(0,1')\}; H:=\{(1,2),(1',2)\}
$$

Comment: What does 1′ mean?

Comment: Just a symbol not equal to $1$.

Comment: OMG dude,thanks.You saved my Algebra semester